# awk search and replace for specific fields

Tags: awk

For Excel purposes I need to create a CSV file with a exact format, where some columns are temperatures presented as floats. This is my input file structure:

```
'14/11/09 00:00  13.0C  25.1C  26.5C  25.4C  26.3C  25.0C    ***    ***   Some text Control
'14/11/10 08:49                                                           POWER ON
```

So far I'm able to get rid of "dot" to have "comma" instead. I have multiple files and I made a list of them. This list I'm passing to my script, which reads it line by line (`$line` represents input file):

```
grep "'" $line | tr -s " "  | sed -e "s/'//g" | cut -d" " -f 1-15 |
grep "\*\*\*" | sed -e "s/\./,/g" > $basename"_measurements.csv"

14/11/09 00:00 13,0C 25,1C 26,5C 25,4C 26,3C 25,0C *** *** Some text Control
```

Excel does not accept `13,0C` as number. But I simply don't have any idea how to get rid of this "C" close to number, eg: `"13,0C"` and so on. I cannot do `sed` on whole line cause I will broke text in columns (eg. last column). I thought of using `awk` on columns `3-8` and pipe them to `sed`. But it gets more and more complicated. Maybe there is a smarter way to do it?

Comment: Yes, a single awk script on it's own. Show the desired output given that input. The first line is trivial to deal with but the second with all of those blank "fields" might be more challenging depending on what you want your output to look like. wrt `So far im able to get rid of "dot" to have "comma" instead` -that obviously would change `25.1` to `25,1` which would split the number into 2 separate fields in the output CSV so - why is that desirable?

Comment: What exactly is the 'exact format' you need to create?  You say CSV, but then try to use comma as the decimal point, which is pretty much inimical to the 'comma as field separator' specification.  You can get rid of the C with `sed 's/\([0-9]\)C/\1/g'` (replace a digit followed by C with just the digit).  The whole lot should probably be done in a single `awk` script, though.  You should really show the desired output rather than, or as well as, the current actual output.

Comment: this is what i want: "14/11/09 00:00 13,0 25,1 26,5 25,4 26,3 25,0 *** *** Some text Control"  - just to get rid of "C" close to numbers. CSV separator is "space"

Answer (score 0):

this will trim all C next to a digit

```
sed -r 's/([0-9])C/\1/g'
```

if you want to do the replacement only with certain fields, you'll have better control with `awk`